# How can I add dynamic page title in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, oop, laravel-5

I want to add a dynamic page title like I have a post list and when I click on a single post details page open, in that case, I want that dynamic title to be displayed in head title file.

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title', 'This is {{$post->title}} Post Page')
@section('contents')
<h3>{{$post->title}}</h3>
<p>{{$post->body}}</p>
@endsection
```

You can see in this section. 
     @section('title', 'This is {{$post->title}} Post Page')
{{$post->title}} but its not working.. 
its showing something like this.

> This is title); ?> Post Page

And on app.blade.php I have something like this.

```
<title>Laravel Practice - @yield('title')</title>
```

Comment: Look at the example given in https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#template-inheritance

Comment: `@section('title', 'This is ' . $post->title . ' Post Page')`

Comment: thanks buddy `@section('title', 'This is ' . $post->title . ' Post Page')` its working fine ..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Blade's variable syntax isn't valid in a `@section` call, so you'll want to use plain old PHP:

```
@section('title', 'This is ' . $post->title . ' Post Page')
```

If `$post->title` is user input, you're going to want to escape things to be safe from XSS vulnerabilities:

```
@section('title', 'This is ' . e($post->title) . ' Post Page')
```

Comment: thanks alto buddy its really  helpful for me .. and its working perfectly fine, as i need it.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't skip the updated version with `e()`!

Comment: it's working ! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can't leave {{$post->title}} inside '', just put it out and connect with '.' like this :

```
@section('title', 'This is' . {{$post->title}} . 'Post Page')
```

Comment: `@section('title', 'This is ' . $post->title . ' Post Page')` its working, you code was giving this error _FatalErrorException in c57ac69c9752d3a68a86fa12b10b7c767687e517.php line 1:
syntax error, unexpected '<'_